# How to read from file using Chaquopy?

Tags: android, python, chaquopy

I want to read a file using Chaquopy. After some errors like "PermissionError" I wrote the same code in Python Idle and Chaquopy:

This code in Idle writes 'True' in output.

```
import xlrd, os
filename = 'F:/q1.xlsx'
print(os.path.isfile(filename))
```

And this one in Chaquopy outputs 'False':

```
import xlrd, os
filename = 'F:/q1.xlsx'
self.findViewById(R.id.label).setText(str(os.path.isfile(filename)))
```

I tried all the described combinations of '\' and '/'. It also cannot open a file in the same folder with Python activity if I write only its relative path. How to make Chaquopy work with files correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access files either using `pkgutil` or by using the `extractPackages` setting. See [the documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#resource-files) for details.

Comment: Thank you! Pkgutil works for me with text files, I could particularly solve my problem using csv format. But I want to open xlsx file using xlrd module. So I suppose I should use extractPackages. Where should I put it and what should it contain besides my file? I am very sorry but I couldn't find it in documentation.

Comment: It's described in the link in my answer.